# Faster performance for normalizing a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, normalization

I am currently normalizing an numpy array in python created by splicing an image by windows with a stride which creates about 20K patches. The current normalization implementation is a big pain point in my runtime, and I'm trying to replace it with the same functionality done maybe in a C extension or something. I am looking to see what advice the community has to get this done easily and simple? 
Current runtime is about 0.34s just for the normalization part, I'm trying to get below 0.1s or better. You can see creating patches is extremely efficient with view_as_windows, and I am looking for something similar for normalization. Note you can simply comment/uncomment the lines labeled " # ---- Normalization" to see the runtimes yourself for the different implementations.

Here is the current implementation:

```
import gc
import cv2, time
from libraries import GCN
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows


def create_imageArray(patch_list):
    returnImageArray = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(patch_list), 1, 40, 60))
    idx = 0
    for patch, name, coords in patch_list:
        imgArray = numpy.asarray(patch[:,:], dtype=numpy.float32)
        imgArray = imgArray[numpy.newaxis, ...]
        returnImageArray[idx] = imgArray
        idx += 1
    return returnImageArray
    # print "normImgArray[0]:",normImgArray[0]


def NormalizeData(imageArray):
    tempImageArray = imageArray

    # Normalize the data in batches
    batchSize = 25000
    dataSize = tempImageArray.shape[0]
    imageChannels = tempImageArray.shape[1]
    imageHeight = tempImageArray.shape[2]
    imageWidth = tempImageArray.shape[3]

    for i in xrange(0, dataSize, batchSize):
        stop = i + batchSize
        print("Normalizing data [{0} to {1}]...".format(i, stop))
        dataTemp = tempImageArray[i:stop]
        dataTemp = dataTemp.reshape(dataTemp.shape[0], imageChannels * imageHeight * imageWidth)
        #print("Performing GCN [{0} to {1}]...".format(i, stop))
        dataTemp = GCN(dataTemp)
        #print("Reshaping data again [{0} to {1}]...".format(i, stop))
        dataTemp = dataTemp.reshape(dataTemp.shape[0], imageChannels, imageHeight, imageWidth)
        #print("Updating data with new values [{0} to {1}]...".format(i, stop))
        tempImageArray[i:stop] = dataTemp
    del dataTemp
    gc.collect()

    return tempImageArray


start_time = time.time()
img1_path = "777628-1032-0048.jpg"
img_list = ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg", "images/4.jpg", "images/5.jpg"]

patchWidth = 60
patchHeight = 40
channels = 1
stride = patchWidth/6
multiplier = 1.31
finalImgArray = []
vaw_time = 0
norm_time = 0
array_time = 0

for im_path in img_list:
    start = time.time()
    baseFileWithExt = os.path.basename(im_path)
    baseFile = os.path.splitext(baseFileWithExt)[0]
    img = cv2.imread(im_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    nxtWidth = 800
    nxtHeight = 1200
    patchesList = []
    for i in xrange(7):
        img = cv2.resize(img, (nxtWidth, nxtHeight))
        nxtWidth = int(nxtWidth//multiplier)
        nxtHeight = int(nxtHeight//multiplier)
        patches = view_as_windows(img, (patchHeight, patchWidth), stride)
        cols = patches.shape[0]
        rows = patches.shape[1]
        patchCount = cols*rows
        print "patchCount:",patchCount, "     patches.shape:",patches.shape
        returnImageArray = numpy.zeros(shape=(patchCount, channels, patchHeight, patchWidth))
        idx = 0

        for col in xrange(cols):
            for row in xrange(rows):
                patch = patches[col][row]
                imageName = "{0}-patch{1}-{2}.jpg".format(baseFile, i, idx)
                patchCoodrinates = (0, 1, 2, 3)  # don't need these for example
                patchesList.append((patch, imageName, patchCoodrinates))
                # ---- Normalization inside 7 iterations <> Part 1
                # imgArray = numpy.asarray(patch[:,:], dtype=numpy.float32)
                # imgArray = patch.astype(numpy.float32)
                # imgArray = imgArray[numpy.newaxis, ...] # Add a new axis for channel so goes from shape [40,60] to [1,40,60]
                # returnImageArray[idx] = imgArray
                idx += 1

        # if i == 0: finalImgArray = returnImageArray
        # else: finalImgArray = numpy.concatenate((finalImgArray, returnImageArray), axis=0)

    vaw_time += time.time() - start

    # ---- Normalizaion inside 7 iterations <> Part 2
    # start = time.time()
    # normImageArray = NormalizeData(finalImgArray)
    # norm_time += time.time() - start
    # print "returnImageArray.shape:", finalImgArray.shape

    # ---- Normalization outside 7 iterations
    start = time.time()
    imgArray = create_imageArray(patchesList)
    array_time += time.time() - start

    start = time.time()
    normImgArray = NormalizeData( imgArray )
    norm_time += time.time() - start
    print "len(patchesList):",len(patchesList)


total_time = (time.time() - start_time)/len(img_list)
print "\npatches_time per img: {0:.3f} s".format(vaw_time/len(img_list))
print "create imgArray per img: {0:.3f} s".format(array_time/len(img_list))
print "normalization_time per img: {0:.3f} s".format(norm_time/len(img_list))
print "total time per image: {0:.3f} s \n".format(total_time)
```

Here is the GCN code in case you need to download it to use it: http://pastebin.com/RdVMD2P3

**Details on code inside GCN**

I am calling GCN using the default params.
[image: GCN Params]

At high level it is taking the average of all of the pixels and dividing all the pixels by that average. So if there's an an image array that looks like this [1 2 3], then the average is 2. Therefore we divide each number by 2 and get [0.5, 1, 1.5]. That's what the normalize does. I forgot to highlight in the image above the mean = X.mean(axis=1).
[image: Normalization function]

Notes: 
If you are wondering why I am re-iterating and creating a new imgArray to normalize instead of doing it in the original patch creation it is to keep data transfer to a minimum. I am implementing this with the multiprocess library, and serializing data takes a LOOONG time, so trying to keep the data serialization to a minimum (meaning pass as little data back from the process). I have measured the difference between doing inside the 7 loops or outside, and notes are below so I can deal with that. However if you know of a faster implementation, do let me know.

Runtimes for creating imageArray inside 7 loops:

```
patches_time per img: 0.560 s
normalization_time per img: 0.336 s
total time per image: 0.896 s
```

Runtimes for creating imageArray and normalizing outside of 7 iterations:

```
patches_time per img: 0.040 s
create imgArray per img: 0.146 s
normalization_time per img: 0.339 s
total time per image: 0.524 s
```

I didn't see this before, but it seems creating the array is also taking some time.

Comment: a couple of quick points (to further investigate) 1. dont use arrays, try to use a more direct binary structure (not sure what as i dont use numpy) 2. try to reduce nested loops into one loop (loop composition) and try to use loop unrolling where applicable 3. cache values that are re-used instead of re-computing them

Comment: what exactly does `NormalizeData` procedure do (gaussian normalisation maybe?)?

Comment: from your metrics it seems `normalisation_time` is the bottleneck and this depends both on what it does and on the chosen representation of the data used as parameters

Comment: I forgot to add the NormalizeData code. I made a pastebin on my mobile, i will add it tomorrow to the question: http://pastebin.com/gNsSm4ds

Comment: Eech.  Code is messy - you would get more help if you isolate the code actually doing the normalization.  That said, it looks like you're normalizing based on the patch surrounding a given pixel.  In this case you can efficiently get the total sum of luminance in the square surrounding the pixel using the Integral Image.

Comment: So far I see a whole lot of reshaping, but still not the actual code that performs the normalization (do you really need so many nested function calls?).

Comment: I just added the normalization code, I had forgotten to before.